# Error in rmagick installation in ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hiall,

I am new to ROR . I am trying to install rmagick on my local machine . When I try to install it everytime i get the following error :
Please help me out with this situation .

```
D:\ruby\bin>gem install rmagick  --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=D:\ruby\Rmmagik\lib --with-opt-include=D:\ruby\Rmmagik\include   Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

D:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-opt-lib=D:\ruby\Rmmagik\lib --with-opt-include=D:\ruby\Rmmagik\include
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=D:/ruby/bin/ruby
Gem files will remain installed in D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

Thanks in advance

Surjan

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a header file.

It looks like you're on Windows, right?

If so, a simple solution may be to download the pre-built ImageMagick binary for Windows.

[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php?ImageMagick=rdfgqvr16sq8ngvahkosd26om0#windows)

If you're on Debian or Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

(Editors, feel free to add solutions for other platforms)

Comment: Hi Joe , thanks for your response , yes i am using windows.I have already downloaded the exe file for windows : "ImageMagick-6.7.6-4-Q8-windows-dll.exe" and installed it under this path "D:\ruby\Rmmagik\", Also I have set the class and lib path for the same .  Please help me in this regard